How do I use the set_drag_forwarding() function correctly?
I am trying to make a drag and drop inventory in godot using the set_drag_forwarding() method. However I am getting an error Method expected 2 arguments but called 1 when I try to use this function. I figure I am using it wrong because I do not know how I would pass arguments in this way.
My code:
extends PanelContainer

const ITEM_SLOT_SCENE = preload("res://game_objects/inventory/item_slot.tscn")

@onready var item_grid = find_child("item_grid")

var inventory: Inventory = null 

func set_inventory(inventory: Inventory) -> void:
    self.inventory = inventory
    
    inventory.connect("slot_changed", _on_inventory_slot_changed)
    
    for i in inventory.max_slots:
        var stack = inventory.get_item_stack(i)
        var slot = ITEM_SLOT_SCENE.instantiate()
        slot.set_drag_forwarding(get_drag_data_fw, can_drop_data_fw, drop_data_fw)
        item_grid.add_child(slot)
        slot.set_item(i, stack.item, stack.quantity)
        
func can_drop_data_fw(position: Vector2, data, other_control: Control) -> bool:
    if not other_control is ItemSlot:
        return false
        
    if not data.has("slot") or data.slot.inventory_index == other_control.inventory_index:
        return false
    
    return true

func get_drag_data_fw(position: Vector2, other_control: Control):
    if not other_control is ItemSlot or not other_control.item:
        return null
        
    other_control = other_control as ItemSlot
    
    # set_drag_preview
    
    return {"slot": other_control}

func drop_data_fw(position: Vector2, data, other_control: Control) -> void:
    if not other_control is ItemSlot:
        return
    
    inventory.swap_slots(data.slot.inventory_index, other_control.inventory_index)

func _on_inventory_slot_changed(index: int, old_content: ItemStack, new_content: ItemStack) -> void:
    for child in item_grid.get_children():
        if not child is ItemSlot:
            continue
        
        child = child as ItemSlot
        
        if child.inventory_index == index:
            child.set_item(index, new_content.item, new_content.quantity)
            break

I have tried just putting self as the only parameter of set_drag_forwarding because that is what I have seen online, but I think that is outdated as of Godot 4.

The get_drag_data_fw, can_drop_data_fw, drop_data_fw function signatures must match their _get_drag_data, _can_drop_data, _drop_data counterparts.
In the code you posted your fw functions take the extra argument other_control.
I think you may want to do
slot.set_drag_forwarding(
    get_drag_data_fw.bind(the_other_control),
    can_drop_data_fw.bind(the_other_control),
    drop_data_fw.bind(the_other_control),
)

